# Cocos2d JS XMLHTTPRequest is not defined

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-iphone, xmlhttprequest, cocos2d-js

**Hello Guys,**

I currently have the problem, that XMLHTTTPRequests are not working in Cocos2d JS Version 3.8.1.

I have a file with only one important line:

```
var xhr = cc.loader.getXMLHttpRequest();
```

If i run this in my Browser (Chrome) everything works fine and no errors are occuring.
But if I try to run it with XCode in the Simulator I get the following error:

```
..../script/jsb_boot.js:360:ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
```

Was anybody else able to crate a XMLHTTPRequest with Cocos2d JS?
Do I have to include something in the AppDelegate.cpp?
Or is it simply not possible in this version? (What I don't think and hope...)

Kind regards

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Trying to provide the solution. Feel free to correct if there is something wrong in my answer.

If you have a Visual Studio, you can open win32 solution with it. And add in AppDelegate.cpp

```
#include "network/XMLHTTPRequest.h"

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
{   .......
sc->addRegisterCallback(MinXmlHttpRequest::_js_register);
.......
}
```

And then add the libNetwork subproject, and libNetwork.lib in linker input of your project.

You may also want to refer to the reference below. You may need to use translation feature if you don't understand Chinese :)

[Using JSB-Bindings in Visual Studio Chukong Documentation](https://github.com/chukong/cocos-docs/blob/master/manual/framework/html5/jsb/jsb-extension/zh.md)

Hope it will help.